# "[" and "]" characters mess up get-childitem

Tags: powershell, directory, get-childitem

Using PowerShell 4.0,
I am trying to get the size of multiple directories and I am getting very inconsistent results between what windows tells me and what my code is telling me.

The code in question is:

```
$temp4 = ($folderInfo.rootFolder).fullname
$folderInfo.directories += Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $temp4 -Recurse -Force -Directory
$folderInfo.directories += $folderInfo.rootFolder
foreach ($dir in $folderInfo.directories)
{
    $temp3 = $dir.fullname
    $temp2 = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $temp3 -Force
    $temp = (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir.fullname -Force -File | Measure-Object -Property length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum
    $folderInfo.totalSize += $temp
}
return $folderInfo
```

if `$folderInfo.rootFolder = D:\sample`
then I get what I want
but if `$folderInfo.rootFolder = D:\[sample`
then I get

> Get-ChildItem : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid: sample [sample
>   At C:\powershell scripts\test.ps1:55 char:12
>   +         $temp = (Get-ChildItem $dir.fullname -Force -File | Measure-Object -Property l ...
>   +                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

The same holds true if `D:\sample` contains a folder somewhere in it's children that is `"[sample"`. I will get correct results from everything else, but anything in or beyond the problem directory. Both `$dir.pspath` and `$dir.fullname` screw things up.

Edit: changed the above code to reflect it's current state and included the full error.
edit again: The code above now has some debugging temp variables.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `-LiteralPath` parameter in place of `-Path` to suppress the wildcard globbing.  Also, since you're using V4, you can use the `-Directory` switch and dispense with the `$_.iscontainer` filter:

```
$folderInfo.directories = 
 Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $folderInfo.rootFolder -Recurse -Force -Directory
```

If you have more squre brackets farther down the directory tree, keep using literpath in subsequent Get-ChildItem commands:

```
$folderInfo.directories += Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $folderInfo.rootFolder -Recurse -Force -Directory
    $folderInfo.directories += Get-Item -LiteralPath $folderInfo.rootFolder
    foreach ($dir in $folderInfo.directories)
    {
        $temp2 = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir.PSPath -Force
        $temp = (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir.fullname -Force -File | Measure-Object -Property length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum
        $folderInfo.totalSize += $temp
    }
    return $folderInfo
```

Comment: i changed up my code to reflect your suggestion, i am still getting the error.

Comment: Edit the question and post the updated code and the exact error message.

Comment: changed my original post

Comment: changed my original answer

Comment: hmm this is odd, i made the changes to match your example, though if the folders with "[" in it is a child folder down the line it works but if it's the root folder it chokes on the same error
this line of code is causing the program when .rootFolder = C:\[sample
$folderInfo.directories += Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $folderInfo.rootFolder -Recurse -Force -Directory

Comment: from what i can tell get-childitem will work with or without -literalpath so long at the string i feed it does not have "[" in it.
the literalPath parameter corrects as expected in the foreach loop though which is odd

Comment: i changed the above code again.
though soon after i figured out the culprit.
the -recurse parameter looks for wildcards regardless of literalPath.
this is assumed based on the details provided for recurse parameter.

Comment: turns out i was over thinking the whole thing, i managed to shrink it all down to one line. i will still have trouble if the root path has any funny wild cards in it.