# Errors with Get-ChildItem and ChDir if the path contains "["

Tags: powershell, wildcard, get-childitem

I am a Powershell newbie, trying to run Get-FileHash over a specific folder. I planned to navigate to the folder first but got an error:

`PS C:\Users\pjmmc\Documents\Genealogy\Family Tree Files> cd "McNab [A1]"`

```
cd : Cannot find path 'McNab [A1]' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd "McNab [A1]"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (McNab [A1]:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

The folder McNab [A1] does exist.

There was also a problem with Get-ChildItem

```
PS C:\Users\pjmmc\Documents\Genealogy\Family Tree Files> dir "McNab [A1]"
PS C:\Users\pjmmc\Documents\Genealogy\Family Tree Files>
```

By a process of elimination, I worked out that [ cannot be used by in a path with Get-ChildItem and probably was special to PowerShell.

I am using PowerShell version 5.1.  The following code was a test to demonstrate that the offending character was [.  I established that the ] character did not cause a problem.

`PS C:\Users\pjmmc\Documents\Genealogy\Family Tree Files> mkdir "["`

PowerShell replied:

```
    Directory: C:\Users\pjmmc\Documents\Genealogy\Family Tree Files  
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        15/06/2022   9:46 PM                [
```

`PS C:\Users\pjmmc\Documents\Genealogy\Family Tree Files> get-childitem "["`

PowerShell Replied

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid: [
At line:1 char:1
+ get-childitem "["
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

I went back to cmd and got the 8.3 name and all was well.  Maybe I could have found that in Powershell, but more interested in getting the job done.

I have a few folders with [  ] in the name.  Is there a workaround for [ as a wildcard in Get-Childitem?

Comment: There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21613997/2983568) here. Besides, I cannot reproduce the issue. Which Powershell version are you using and what exactly is the folder's name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["\[" and "\]" characters mess up get-childitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613997/and-characters-mess-up-get-childitem)

Comment: -LiteralPath solved my problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case try below... -LiteralPath

`Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "C:\tes[t"`

[Powershell - Brackets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/powershell/powershell_brackets.htm)

Interesting GitHub discussion on this issue here.

[Path is not parsed correctly if '[' is present in the path #12168](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12168)